# Multipule listbox, msgbox

Tags: vba, listbox, msgbox

I have 2 listboxes.  If either of the listboxes are selected I wouldl ike a message box pop up when the unselected listbox is trying to be selected saying something.

for example:

if e2>0 and e3>0 then
display messagebox "alsdkjfaslj"
end if

e2 and e3 are cell links from the listboxes.

I can't think of a good way to go about this and am new to vba.  Please help this newbie out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to your worksheet change event for the specific cells you want to trigger your event like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 5).Address = Target.Address Then
        MsgBox ("you clicked E3")
    ElseIf Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 5).Address = Target.Address Then
        MsgBox ("you clicked E2")
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Make sure the code is in the sheet that you want to watch:

[image]